# Get Google Chrome events to appear in Gnome notification area

Tags: notification-area

When I am running Google Chrome browser with Gmail open, I get a pop-up notification for new incoming messages. But I don't get an entry in the notification area, i.e., what you see when you click the date/time display on the top bar. How can I get entries there?

My goal is to see some indication that I have new mail, in case I happened to miss the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gnome shell extension called "Gnome Email Notifications" that works together with "Gnome online accounts" to provide the functionality I was looking for.